# Operation on relation – what is it called?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Given two binary relations $R_1 \subseteq X \times X$ and $R_2 \subseteq Y \times Y$, I can define the following binary relation on $X \times Y$:
$$
R_1 \stackrel?\otimes R_2 := \{ ((x,y),(x,y')) \mid x \in X, y R_2y'\} \cup \{ ((x,y),(x',y)) \mid xR_1x', y \in Y\} 
$$

How is this operations on binary relations usually called?

For some intuition: Let $X$ and $Y$ be the set of expressions in the lambda calculus and both $R_1$ and $R_2$ be $\stackrel\beta\to$, the reduction of *one* redex anywhere in the term. Then we can use the operator above to calculate the one-step reductions of an application (assuming the application is not a redex on its own):
$$
e_1 e_2 \stackrel\beta\to e_1' e_2'
\iff
(e_1, e_2) (\stackrel\beta\to \stackrel?\otimes \stackrel\beta\to) (e_1', e_2').
$$

Comment: You seem to have a couple of typos in your question that make it hard to understand what you actually mean by $R_1 \oplus R_2$.

Comment: I don’t see the typos … ah, found one ($r'$ instead of $y'$)

Comment: You fixed one that confused me but still: The relation, as written, is on $(X \times Y) \times (X \times Y)$ and not on $X \times Y$ as claimed. And I think the question would benefit from a little context - given that the construction seems to be rather unnatural at first sight. With the information given, I'd just say that this operation, whatever it may be used for, simply doesn't have a commonly known name.

Comment: The relation is on $(X \times Y)$, so it is a subset of $(X\times Y) \times (X \times Y)$…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In graph-theoretic terms, this is the [cartesian product of graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs).

It is not identical to what is usually called the "cartesian product of relations", though.

Comment: Heh, I guess that was just too obvious to see :-)